# Mobile Website: Framework focused on Symbian and Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, frameworks, symbian, mobile-website

I received the task to add a mobile-friendly version of our website. Apps for iPhone and Android already exist (and their browsers are really good), so the focus of this website lies on Symbian and Blackberry devices.

As I am a lazy programmer, I wanted to use some frameworks that help me in developing this website. I have found numerous frameworks like iUI or iWebkit that focus on iPhone and Android devices and bring a very nice look and feel to mobile websites. And there are other frameworks like PhoneGap which focus on building applications for mobile devices.

But I have not found a framework that is targetted on mobile websites for Symbian and / or Blackberry. Is there something like that or do I have to start from scratch? Or are the browsers for these devices so bad that I have to write very basic HTML?

Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only know [mobile web templates](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Develop/Web/Mobile_web_browsing/Web_templates/) for UI in nokia phone. They are good for blackberry too

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry browser isn't awful, it gets an Acid3 score of 93/100.

I do the clear majority of my web-browsing on my BlackBerry, almost all of it in Opera Mini. I haven't even tried the Acid tests on Opera Mini, I know it'd just be a waste. :) *But*, Opera means I don't have to do side-to-side scrolling, back and forward are lightning fast (retrieved from memory when they can), it has rudimentary tabs, and the latency is probably 1/10th or better the latency of the native browser.

I'd rather see your application work well in Opera than work perfect in the native browser.

Comment: Thanks - Opera Mini is also on the list, but the majority of Blackberry users on our website use the default browser. That's why I will focus on this one, but I will also check on Opera Mini.

Comment: Blackberry OS 6 will use a modern Webkit based browser.  However prior and existing browsers are mediocre.